# function that looks up keys in a dictionary until there is no more associated values

Tags: python, python-3.7

I need help creating a function that goes through a given dictionary. The value associated with that key may be another key to the dictionary. i need the function to keep looking up the keys until it reaches a key that has no associated value.

```
def follow_me(d, s):

    while d:
        if s in d:
            return d[s]
```

I can return the value in the dictionary that s equals to but I've no idea how to iterate through it until I get a value that has no associated value. So I can get the value that badger is doe, but how do I iterate through the dictionary until I get fox and then fox to hen etc.

```
d = {'badger':'doe', 'doe':'fox', 'fox':'hen','hen':'flea',
'sparrow':'spider', 'zebra':'lion', 'lion':'zebra'}
print(follow_me(d, 'badger'))
print(follow_me(d, 'fox'))
print(follow_me(d, 'sparrow'))
print(follow_me(d, 'zebra'))
print(follow_me(d, 'aardvark'))
```

and this is what I currently have of the function that makes sense to me because everything else I've tried is just wrong.

```
def follow_me(d, s):
    while d:
        if s in d:
            return d[s]
```

and the output needs to be:

```
flea
flea
spider
aardvark
```

but my code right now is producing:

```
doe
hen
spider
lion
```

Comment: That's guaranteed not to happen in this case

Comment: @Moormanly: it's in their example with `'lion'` and `'zebra'`. I'm not sure what they expect it to do though.

Comment: oh with lion and zebra they want it to be printed false but i have't catered for exceptions yet because I can't figure out how to iterate through it

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not getting `aardvark` printed by your code. The function you've shown will run forever when you make the last of your example calls.

Comment: In the example code you've given, `while d:` is equivalent to `while True:` if `d` is a nonempty dictionary and `while False:` if `d` is an empty dictionary. Neither of these is what you want. You could try `while s in d:` and update `s` inside the loop.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the existence of infinite loops this has to be handled. Your description isn't clear about what should happen in this case.

```
def follow_me(d, key):
    visited_keys = []
    while key not in visited_keys and d[key]:
        visited_keys.append(key)
        key = d[key]
    if not d[key]:
        return key
    return "this hunt has no end"
```

Comment: A few comments: You almost never need to use `dic.keys`, you can just use the dictionary directly to get the same effect (this is true of both membership testing and iteration). You also don't need recursion here. Tail recursion can always be transformed by a programmer into a loop, and looping is much more efficient in Python (which doesn't do tail-call optimization).

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you are looking for, though your problem description is very unclear:

```
def follow_me(d, k):
    while k in d:
        k = d[k]
    return k
```

Note that the loop in this function will run forever if there is a cycle between keys and values in your dictionary. Your example has one between `'lion'` and `'zebra'`, and it's not entirely clear how you intend such a cycle to be broken. If you want to expand each key only once, you could handle it by keeping track of the values you've seen so far in a `set`:

```
def follow_me(d, k):
    seen = set()
    while k in d and k not in seen:
        seen.add(k)
        k = d[k]
    return k
```

This will return whichever key in the cycle you reach first (so `follow_me(d, 'zebra')` with your example dictionary will return `'zebra'` after going `zebra => lion => zebra`). If you want some other outcome, you'd need different logic and it might be tricky to do.

If you request a key that's not in the dictionary (like `'aardvark'` in your example), the requested key will be returned immediately. You could add special handling for the first key you look up, but it would again make things more complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly how its supposed to be answered! I've been stuck on it for ages thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To extend on the other answers, which are still valid. If you have a *very* large dictionary then using `key not in dic.keys()` or `k in d` iterates through all keys every loop.

To go around this, one can use a try catch:

```
def follow_me(dic, key):
    while True:
        if key not in dic.keys():
            return key
        key = dic[key]


def follow_me2(dic, key):
    try:
        while True:
            key = dic[key]
    except Exception as e:
        return key

import time
d = { i: (i+1) for i in range(10000000) }
start = time.time()
follow_me(d, 0)
print("Using 'in' takes", time.time() - start,"s")

start = time.time()
follow_me2(d, 0)
print("Using 'try' takes", time.time() - start,"s")
```

gives the output:

```
Using 'in' takes 2.476428747177124 s
Using 'try' takes 0.9100546836853027 s
```