# A non-recursive function follow_me(d, s) where d is a dictionary and s is a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I'm currently studying for an exam and have struggled to solve this question, my biggest problem seems to be iterating through the dictionary properly. The question itself is a non-recursive function follow_me(d, s) where d is a dictionary and s is a string. The string may be a key to the dictionary. The value associated with that key may, in turn, be another key to the dictionary. Keep looking up the keys until you reach a key that has no associated value. Then, return that key.

I've tried working through just the keys and then the values, however, it seems the most ideal way to iterate through is using k,v in d.items(). I'm quite new to python which may not be ideal as I could be lacking some understanding which could be the biggest problem in why I cannot come to a solution.

```
def follow_me(d, s):
    for k,v in d.items():
        try:
            if s == k:
                s = v
                continue

            else:
                return s

        except:
            break
```

```
d = {'badger':'doe', 'doe':'fox', 'fox':'hen','hen':'flea',
'sparrow':'spider', 'zebra':'lion', 'lion':'zebra'}
print(follow_me(d, 'badger'))
print(follow_me(d, 'fox'))
print(follow_me(d, 'sparrow'))
print(follow_me(d, 'zebra'))
print(follow_me(d, 'aardvark'))
```

Expected Results:
flea
flea
spider
False
aardvark

Actual Results:
flea
fox
sparrow
zebra
aardvark

Zebra is expected to be false as it infinitely cycles between zebra and lion. Any help/tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn’t be iterating *over the dictionary* at all.

Comment: Isnt your v supposed to be your value? Why did you take v+1?

Comment: Hm, so how could you possibly go from key to value and vice versa until no associated key is found? Sorry for questioning I just don't see another way.

Comment: @Axios, yes v is the value of the dictionary, the v+1 is supposed to be in the case that the example
below, follow_me(d, 'zebra') must not infinitely cycle between 'zebra' and 'lion'. and If a cycle is detected follow_me should return the boolean False, however, I am quite possibly wrong in using it that way, as said I'm quite inexperienced and it may not apply to dictionaries.

Comment: @Joyce having v+1 is the same as having a string + 1, which will throw back an error. However in this case its not because its not even being used

Comment: Ah, see my problem there is that I was trying to look for a way similar to the way i+1 works when working through say a list, I'll get rid of it.

Comment: @Joyce Not only that, doing `if s == k:` only compares the first item in the dictionary before returning the value, hence 'fox', ..etc will not work. That being said, you shouldnt be iterating through a dictionary like what Davis said, you can try appending it to a list before working on it first! :)

Comment: @Axios Hm, okay well I guess I'll go back to the drawing board and see what I can do, thanks for the help, I'll look into a couple of videos into dictionaries as it seems I'm completely wrong in this area so far to come to a solution.

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531565/function-that-looks-up-keys-in-a-dictionary-until-there-is-no-more-associated-va/57531608#57531608 . And by the way, do you know each other? :)

Comment: @CFLS Wow, no way, I haven't heard of her, however, I'm guessing that she does the same course as its exactly the same, theres quite a lot of people on my course in college.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you don't need to loop over the keys; a simple `while` loop will do.

```
def follow_me(d, s):
    while s in d:
        s = d[s]
    return s
```

That said, you should check for cycles by adding the checked values to a `set`:

```
def follow_me(d, s):
    checked_keys = set()
    while s in d:
        checked_keys.add(s)
        s = d[s]
        if s in checked_keys:
            raise Exception('Cycle detected')
    return s
```

Comment: Didn't quite think it could have been that simple, maybe I looked too much into it was my biggest problem. Rather then raising the exception, I have to return false, as if I do raise it, it breaks the loop. However, thank you very much for that I'll go through it with pythontutor and learn from it.

Comment: This method is clean but will stuck in the `while` loop for `follow_me(d, 'zebra')`. OP wants a way to return `False` for repetitive pattern.

Comment: @HenryYik just replace the raise in the second snippet :)

Comment: Right - overlooked that one.

Comment: Haha, yea I noticed from the very beginning actually to get rid of the raise exception, as it conflicts with the intended output and to replace it instead with return False, I appreciate your educational thought :)

Answer (score 2):

This question requires some background vocabulary and theory to build a solution from.

The input dictionary represents a structure called a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)). Specifically, it's a [directed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph), [disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)) graph because [edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#edge) are not bidirectional (that is, an edge between "badger" and "doe" means we can go from "badger" to "doe" but not necessarily in reverse). The graph is disconnected because it's not possible to get from some [nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)) in the graph to other nodes.

Let's model the graph visually:

```
[badger]-->[doe]-->[fox]-->[hen]-->[flea]


[sparrow]-->[spider]    [zebra]------+
                           ^         |
                           |         v
                           +-------[lion]
```

We can see that there's a [cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) between "zebra" and "lion" and that there are three disconnected subgraphs. Following an edge is as simple as indexing into a key of the dictionary to access its neighbor (nodes in this graph never have more than one neighbor, which is a nice simplification).

Now that we have the conceptual framework in place, the next step is determining how to walk through the graph from a given origin node until we locate a cycle or hit a node that has no outbound edge. There are many ways of doing this, but one way is to run a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on the graph.

Running a DFS in code boils down to using the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) data structure, either in the form of an explicit stack or a [stack of function calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). The pseudocode for a recursive DFS is simple:

```
def DFS(graph, root, target):
    if root == target: return True

    for neighbor in graph[root]:
        if DFS(graph, neighbor, target):
            return True

    return False
```

This works fine on trees, which are directed graphs that have no cycles, but will fail on the provided input because it contains cycles. We can also simplify the DFS since we're guaranteed one neighbor and don't care about a target destination. However, it's necessary to keep track of the terminal node rather than a simple boolean. Putting this together we get the following pseudocode:

```
def DFS(graph: dict, root: str, visited: set):
    if root in visited:
        return False
    elif root not in graph:
        return root

    visited.add(root)
    return DFS(graph, graph[root], visited)
```

This can also be written iteratively as in your attempt like:

```
def follow_me(graph, target):
    visited = set()

    while target in graph:
        if target in visited: return False

        visited.add(target)
        target = graph[target]

    return target
```

Comment: Damn, I cannot believe you put that much effort into helping me, I appreciate it so much. As for it though I do believe I have to approach the cycle in a much more simpler way as illustrated in the other two answers said.  I feel as if I can learn a lot from what you've said that could help me on my way as I become more advanced, so thank you very much, a strong illustration in the question was infact to avoid being trapped by the cycle between zebra  and lion as demonstrated by you in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def follow_me(d, s):
    if s not in d:
        return s 
    else:
        k = [] # save the chain keys
        while (s in d):
            if s in k:
                return False 
            k.append(s)    
            s = d[s]    
        return s

d = {'badger':'doe', 'doe':'fox', 'fox':'hen','hen':'flea',
'sparrow':'spider', 'zebra':'lion', 'lion':'zebra'}
print(follow_me(d, 'badger'))
print(follow_me(d, 'fox'))
print(follow_me(d, 'sparrow'))
print(follow_me(d, 'zebra'))
print(follow_me(d, 'aardvark'))
```

Output

```
flea
flea
spider
False
aardvark
```

The logic is pretty straight forward and the code is self-explanatory.

Comment: This is a question for an educational assignment. This answer offers no explanation and just hands the code over. How is this helpful?

Comment: @ggorlen I dont think this deserves a downvote... People do actually learn from correct solutions. However, that is my humble opinion.

Comment: Thank you @ComplicatedPhenomenom, I appreciate the answer, it may not have been best for me to come straight to the solution rather I adapt a few pieces for learning purposes, however, thank you anyway it really helped!

Comment: Beyond the lack of explanation, other issues: 1) O(n) search over a list on every node element. Why not use a set for O(1) lookups? 2) Single letter variables throughout. 3) Poor style (unnecessary parenthesis around conditional, no space between `v=d[s]`, `v` is a redundant variable, just return `s`?). 4) unnecessary conditional. flakes' solution is much cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: @ggorlen your advice is appreciated.